# Count number of rows between two timestamps

Tags: r

I have data in a dataframe where rows are organized by time-stamp. I need to take each row and look back by 1 hour from that row's time-stamp and calculate number of rows are there within that 1 hour. I tried `zoo` package with `window` but looks like it works with `Date` type not `time-stamp`

My data looks like:

```
    Timestamp   X
1/9/2015 0:00   1
1/9/2015 0:30   2
1/9/2015 1:10   3
1/9/2015 1:30   4
1/9/2015 2:20   5
1/9/2015 2:30   6
1/9/2015 3:15   7
1/9/2015 3:30   8
1/9/2015 4:00   9
1/9/2015 4:30   10
1/9/2015 5:01   11
```

The result should look like:

```
    Timestamp   X   row_count
1/9/2015 0:00   1   0
1/9/2015 0:30   2   1
1/9/2015 1:10   3   1
1/9/2015 1:30   4   2
1/9/2015 2:20   5   1
1/9/2015 2:30   6   2
1/9/2015 3:15   7   2
1/9/2015 3:30   8   2
1/9/2015 4:00   9   2
1/9/2015 4:30   10  2
1/9/2015 5:01   11  2
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

---

EDIT: I've asked a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925686/count-rows-since-a-date-condition-is-met).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a `data.frame`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)

dt[.(Timestamp = Timestamp - 1*60*60, X = X), on = 'Timestamp', roll = -Inf,
   i.X - X]
# [1] 0 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1
```

Comment: Thank you eddi.. Indeed I am using `data.frame` and kind of new to `data.table`. Thanks for helping