# Count rows since a date condition is met

Tags: r, data.table, time-series

I have a R data.table with following columns

```
Date    Time    X   Y   
5/9/2016    12:00:00 AM 30  125 
5/9/2016    12:30:00 AM 27  127 
5/9/2016    1:00:00 AM  30  133 
5/9/2016    1:30:00 AM  25  115 
5/9/2016    2:00:00 AM  26  116 
5/9/2016    3:00:00 AM  34  128 
5/9/2016    3:30:00 AM  34  120 
5/9/2016    4:00:00 AM  26  133 
5/9/2016    5:00:00 AM  35  119 
5/9/2016    5:30:00 AM  35  126 
5/9/2016    6:00:00 AM  35  118 
5/9/2016    6:30:00 AM  28  120 
5/9/2016    7:00:00 AM  29  123 
5/9/2016    7:30:00 AM  30  125 
5/9/2016    8:30:00 AM  35  116 
5/9/2016    9:00:00 AM  32  123 
5/9/2016    9:30:00 AM  33  135 
5/9/2016    10:00:00 AM 32  127 
5/9/2016    10:30:00 AM 26  122 
5/9/2016    11:00:00 AM 28  122 
5/9/2016    11:30:00 AM 31  129 
5/9/2016    12:00:00 PM 29  127 
5/9/2016    12:30:00 PM 26  120 
5/9/2016    1:00:00 PM  32  126 
5/9/2016    1:30:00 PM  26  117 
5/9/2016    2:30:00 PM  32  133 
5/9/2016    3:00:00 PM  31  120 
5/9/2016    3:30:00 PM  35  129 
5/9/2016    4:00:00 PM  30  121 
5/9/2016    4:30:00 PM  35  132 
5/9/2016    5:00:00 PM  27  129 
5/9/2016    5:30:00 PM  27  122 
5/9/2016    6:00:00 PM  28  121 
5/9/2016    6:30:00 PM  35  127 
5/9/2016    7:00:00 PM  34  132 
5/9/2016    7:30:00 PM  25  133 
5/9/2016    8:00:00 PM  34  119 
5/9/2016    8:30:00 PM  33  125 
5/9/2016    9:00:00 PM  29  120 
5/9/2016    9:30:00 PM  34  125 
5/9/2016    10:00:00 PM 31  118 
5/9/2016    10:30:00 PM 33  118 
5/9/2016    11:00:00 PM 28  115 
5/9/2016    11:30:00 PM 34  126 
5/10/2016   12:00:00 AM 34  131 
5/10/2016   12:30:00 AM 25  130 
5/10/2016   1:00:00 AM  28  129 
5/10/2016   1:30:00 AM  26  132
```

And I want output like below -

```
Date    Time    X   Y   Rowcount@6hours
    5/9/2016    12:00:00 AM 30  125 0
    5/9/2016    12:30:00 AM 27  127 1
    5/9/2016    1:00:00 AM  30  133 2
    5/9/2016    1:30:00 AM  25  115 3
    5/9/2016    2:00:00 AM  26  116 4
    5/9/2016    3:00:00 AM  34  128 5
    5/9/2016    3:30:00 AM  34  120 6
    5/9/2016    4:00:00 AM  26  133 7
    5/9/2016    5:00:00 AM  35  119 8
    5/9/2016    5:30:00 AM  35  126 9
    5/9/2016    6:00:00 AM  35  118 10
    5/9/2016    6:30:00 AM  28  120 10
    5/9/2016    7:00:00 AM  29  123 10
    5/9/2016    7:30:00 AM  30  125 10
    5/9/2016    8:30:00 AM  35  116 9
    5/9/2016    9:00:00 AM  32  123 10
    5/9/2016    9:30:00 AM  33  135 10
    5/9/2016    10:00:00 AM 32  127 10
    5/9/2016    10:30:00 AM 26  122 10
    5/9/2016    11:00:00 AM 28  122 11
    5/9/2016    11:30:00 AM 31  129 11
    5/9/2016    12:00:00 PM 29  127 11
    5/9/2016    12:30:00 PM 26  120 11
    5/9/2016    1:00:00 PM  32  126 11
    5/9/2016    1:30:00 PM  26  117 11
    5/9/2016    2:30:00 PM  32  133 11
    5/9/2016    3:00:00 PM  31  120 11
    5/9/2016    3:30:00 PM  35  129 11
    5/9/2016    4:00:00 PM  30  121 11
    5/9/2016    4:30:00 PM  35  132 11
    5/9/2016    5:00:00 PM  27  129 11
    5/9/2016    5:30:00 PM  27  122 11
    5/9/2016    6:00:00 PM  28  121 11
    5/9/2016    6:30:00 PM  35  127 11
    5/9/2016    7:00:00 PM  34  132 11
    5/9/2016    7:30:00 PM  25  133 11
    5/9/2016    8:00:00 PM  34  119 11
    5/9/2016    8:30:00 PM  33  125 11
    5/9/2016    9:00:00 PM  29  120 12
    5/9/2016    9:30:00 PM  34  125 12
    5/9/2016    10:00:00 PM 31  118 12
    5/9/2016    10:30:00 PM 33  118 12
    5/9/2016    11:00:00 PM 28  115 12
    5/9/2016    11:30:00 PM 34  126 12
    5/10/2016   12:00:00 AM 34  131 12
    5/10/2016   12:30:00 AM 25  130 12
    5/10/2016   1:00:00 AM  28  129 12
    5/10/2016   1:30:00 AM  26  132 12
```

So my objective is to count number of rows that I have got in last n hours (in example n=6) and append it to each row (I want to use that value to determine the `width` parameter in `rollmean` functions). Here data granularity is at 30 minutes but it can change up to seconds level (and can be nonuniform too!) and there could be missing rows

I tried with `window.zoo` and `xts` but could not arrive at a solution. I posted the same question in another link and the response there works within a single day but not across days [Count number of rows between two timestamps in R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46857193/count-number-of-rows-between-two-timestamps-in-r-dataframe/46857514#46857514)

Comment: Are you aware that you have 2015 dates in `Date`? (Rows 3 & 10)

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and post the output of `dput(<your_data.table>)`. This will help to save time of those who are willing to help you. Please, see also [mcve]. Thank you.

Comment: I edited the input and the output in an excel to showcase how my input and what my output should look like. Apologies for confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
# convert to a 'data.table' (if necessary)
# add a datetime & rowid variable
DT <- as.data.table(df)[, `:=` (DateTime = as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Time), format = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S%p'),
                                rid = .I)][]

# calculate the count with a rolling join
DT[, count6hr := DT[.(DateTime = DateTime - 6*60*60, rid = rid)
                    , on = 'DateTime'
                    , roll = -Inf
                    , mult = 'last'
                    , i.rid - rid]][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>          Date       Time  X   Y            DateTime rid count6hr
>  1:  5/9/2016 12:00:00AM 30 125 2016-05-09 00:00:00   1        0
>  2:  5/9/2016 12:30:00AM 27 127 2016-05-09 00:30:00   2        1
>  3:  5/9/2016  1:00:00AM 30 133 2016-05-09 01:00:00   3        2
>  4:  5/9/2016  1:30:00AM 25 115 2016-05-09 01:30:00   4        3
>  5:  5/9/2016  2:00:00AM 26 116 2016-05-09 02:00:00   5        4
>  6:  5/9/2016  3:00:00AM 34 128 2016-05-09 03:00:00   6        5
>  7:  5/9/2016  3:30:00AM 34 120 2016-05-09 03:30:00   7        6
>  8:  5/9/2016  4:00:00AM 26 133 2016-05-09 04:00:00   8        7
>  9:  5/9/2016  5:00:00AM 35 119 2016-05-09 05:00:00   9        8
> 10:  5/9/2016  5:30:00AM 35 126 2016-05-09 05:30:00  10        9
> 11:  5/9/2016  6:00:00AM 35 118 2016-05-09 06:00:00  11       10
> 12:  5/9/2016  6:30:00AM 28 120 2016-05-09 06:30:00  12       10
> 13:  5/9/2016  7:00:00AM 29 123 2016-05-09 07:00:00  13       10
> 14:  5/9/2016  7:30:00AM 30 125 2016-05-09 07:30:00  14       10
> 15:  5/9/2016  8:30:00AM 35 116 2016-05-09 08:30:00  15        9
> 16:  5/9/2016  9:00:00AM 32 123 2016-05-09 09:00:00  16       10
> 17:  5/9/2016  9:30:00AM 33 135 2016-05-09 09:30:00  17       10
> 18:  5/9/2016 10:00:00AM 32 127 2016-05-09 10:00:00  18       10
> 19:  5/9/2016 10:30:00AM 26 122 2016-05-09 10:30:00  19       10
> 20:  5/9/2016 11:00:00AM 28 122 2016-05-09 11:00:00  20       11
> 21:  5/9/2016 11:30:00AM 31 129 2016-05-09 11:30:00  21       11
> 22:  5/9/2016 12:00:00PM 29 127 2016-05-09 12:00:00  22       11
> 23:  5/9/2016 12:30:00PM 26 120 2016-05-09 12:30:00  23       11
> 24:  5/9/2016  1:00:00PM 32 126 2016-05-09 13:00:00  24       11
> 25:  5/9/2016  1:30:00PM 26 117 2016-05-09 13:30:00  25       11
> 26:  5/9/2016  2:30:00PM 32 133 2016-05-09 14:30:00  26       11
> 27:  5/9/2016  3:00:00PM 31 120 2016-05-09 15:00:00  27       11
> 28:  5/9/2016  3:30:00PM 35 129 2016-05-09 15:30:00  28       11
> 29:  5/9/2016  4:00:00PM 30 121 2016-05-09 16:00:00  29       11
> 30:  5/9/2016  4:30:00PM 35 132 2016-05-09 16:30:00  30       11
> 31:  5/9/2016  5:00:00PM 27 129 2016-05-09 17:00:00  31       11
> 32:  5/9/2016  5:30:00PM 27 122 2016-05-09 17:30:00  32       11
> 33:  5/9/2016  6:00:00PM 28 121 2016-05-09 18:00:00  33       11
> 34:  5/9/2016  6:30:00PM 35 127 2016-05-09 18:30:00  34       11
> 35:  5/9/2016  7:00:00PM 34 132 2016-05-09 19:00:00  35       11
> 36:  5/9/2016  7:30:00PM 25 133 2016-05-09 19:30:00  36       11
> 37:  5/9/2016  8:00:00PM 34 119 2016-05-09 20:00:00  37       11
> 38:  5/9/2016  8:30:00PM 33 125 2016-05-09 20:30:00  38       12
> 39:  5/9/2016  9:00:00PM 29 120 2016-05-09 21:00:00  39       12
> 40:  5/9/2016  9:30:00PM 34 125 2016-05-09 21:30:00  40       12
> 41:  5/9/2016 10:00:00PM 31 118 2016-05-09 22:00:00  41       12
> 42:  5/9/2016 10:30:00PM 33 118 2016-05-09 22:30:00  42       12
> 43:  5/9/2016 11:00:00PM 28 115 2016-05-09 23:00:00  43       12
> 44:  5/9/2016 11:30:00PM 34 126 2016-05-09 23:30:00  44       12
> 45: 5/10/2016 12:00:00AM 34 131 2016-05-10 00:00:00  45       12
> 46: 5/10/2016 12:30:00AM 25 130 2016-05-10 00:30:00  46       12
> 47: 5/10/2016  1:00:00AM 28 129 2016-05-10 01:00:00  47       12
> 48: 5/10/2016  1:30:00AM 26 132 2016-05-10 01:30:00  48       12
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This can also be solved using a *non-equi join*:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(df)[
  , ts :=  lubridate::mdy_hms(paste(Date, Time))][
    , cnt := .SD[.(t6 = ts - 6*60*60, t0 = ts), 
                 on = .(ts >= t6, ts < t0), .N, by = .EACHI]$N][]
```

> ```
>          Date     Time ampm  X   Y                  ts cnt
>  1:  5/9/2016 12:00:00   AM 30 125 2016-05-09 00:00:00   0
>  2:  5/9/2016 12:30:00   AM 27 127 2016-05-09 00:30:00   1
>  3:  5/9/2016  1:00:00   AM 30 133 2016-05-09 01:00:00   2
>  4:  5/9/2016  1:30:00   AM 25 115 2016-05-09 01:30:00   3
>  5:  5/9/2016  2:00:00   AM 26 116 2016-05-09 02:00:00   4
>  6:  5/9/2016  3:00:00   AM 34 128 2016-05-09 03:00:00   5
>  7:  5/9/2016  3:30:00   AM 34 120 2016-05-09 03:30:00   6
>  8:  5/9/2016  4:00:00   AM 26 133 2016-05-09 04:00:00   7
>  9:  5/9/2016  5:00:00   AM 35 119 2016-05-09 05:00:00   8
> 10:  5/9/2016  5:30:00   AM 35 126 2016-05-09 05:30:00   9
> 11:  5/9/2016  6:00:00   AM 35 118 2016-05-09 06:00:00  10
> 12:  5/9/2016  6:30:00   AM 28 120 2016-05-09 06:30:00  10
> 13:  5/9/2016  7:00:00   AM 29 123 2016-05-09 07:00:00  10
> 14:  5/9/2016  7:30:00   AM 30 125 2016-05-09 07:30:00  10
> 15:  5/9/2016  8:30:00   AM 35 116 2016-05-09 08:30:00   9
> 16:  5/9/2016  9:00:00   AM 32 123 2016-05-09 09:00:00  10
> 17:  5/9/2016  9:30:00   AM 33 135 2016-05-09 09:30:00  10
> 18:  5/9/2016 10:00:00   AM 32 127 2016-05-09 10:00:00  10
> 19:  5/9/2016 10:30:00   AM 26 122 2016-05-09 10:30:00  10
> 20:  5/9/2016 11:00:00   AM 28 122 2016-05-09 11:00:00  11
> 21:  5/9/2016 11:30:00   AM 31 129 2016-05-09 11:30:00  11
> 22:  5/9/2016 12:00:00   PM 29 127 2016-05-09 12:00:00  11
> 23:  5/9/2016 12:30:00   PM 26 120 2016-05-09 12:30:00  11
> 24:  5/9/2016  1:00:00   PM 32 126 2016-05-09 13:00:00  11
> 25:  5/9/2016  1:30:00   PM 26 117 2016-05-09 13:30:00  11
> 26:  5/9/2016  2:30:00   PM 32 133 2016-05-09 14:30:00  11
> 27:  5/9/2016  3:00:00   PM 31 120 2016-05-09 15:00:00  11
> 28:  5/9/2016  3:30:00   PM 35 129 2016-05-09 15:30:00  11
> 29:  5/9/2016  4:00:00   PM 30 121 2016-05-09 16:00:00  11
> 30:  5/9/2016  4:30:00   PM 35 132 2016-05-09 16:30:00  11
> 31:  5/9/2016  5:00:00   PM 27 129 2016-05-09 17:00:00  11
> 32:  5/9/2016  5:30:00   PM 27 122 2016-05-09 17:30:00  11
> 33:  5/9/2016  6:00:00   PM 28 121 2016-05-09 18:00:00  11
> 34:  5/9/2016  6:30:00   PM 35 127 2016-05-09 18:30:00  11
> 35:  5/9/2016  7:00:00   PM 34 132 2016-05-09 19:00:00  11
> 36:  5/9/2016  7:30:00   PM 25 133 2016-05-09 19:30:00  11
> 37:  5/9/2016  8:00:00   PM 34 119 2016-05-09 20:00:00  11
> 38:  5/9/2016  8:30:00   PM 33 125 2016-05-09 20:30:00  12
> 39:  5/9/2016  9:00:00   PM 29 120 2016-05-09 21:00:00  12
> 40:  5/9/2016  9:30:00   PM 34 125 2016-05-09 21:30:00  12
> 41:  5/9/2016 10:00:00   PM 31 118 2016-05-09 22:00:00  12
> 42:  5/9/2016 10:30:00   PM 33 118 2016-05-09 22:30:00  12
> 43:  5/9/2016 11:00:00   PM 28 115 2016-05-09 23:00:00  12
> 44:  5/9/2016 11:30:00   PM 34 126 2016-05-09 23:30:00  12
> 45: 5/10/2016 12:00:00   AM 34 131 2016-05-10 00:00:00  12
> 46: 5/10/2016 12:30:00   AM 25 130 2016-05-10 00:30:00  12
> 47: 5/10/2016  1:00:00   AM 28 129 2016-05-10 01:00:00  12
> 48: 5/10/2016  1:30:00   AM 26 132 2016-05-10 01:30:00  12
>          Date     Time ampm  X   Y                  ts cnt
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your help too!